# Young adult fantasy trilogy with a large symbol and coloured background

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I'm looking for a trilogy of books that I was reading at school, back in the early- to mid-2000's. The school library had all three so I guess they might have been published a couple years before that.

The main bits I remember are, the book covers each had a different colour with a large symbol/rune.

I think there were magic books which the main character had to collect?

I can kind of remember some bits of the story:

- I think the character had to go into some sort of labyrinth or series of rooms to retrieve something or talk to someone.
- I remember him traveling by boat through the land.
- There was some sort of 'magical site' and he had to cast a spell there, or protect something from his enemies. I remember that being a major event, possibly in book 1.

I never read the last book, I think someone borrowed it from the library and never returned it.

I live in England, and I read it in English.

The book covers were a solid background of colour, one was dark blue/purple. another was red and yellow I think. But I remember the blue one most. Maybe that was the first or second book?

I think there was a circle symbol and a triangle symbol, don't remember the third.

I think it was a medieval setting.

Comment: Gotta hate those who don't return books to the library. Anyway, welcome! That's already a good bunch of info but maybe you could take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028) too see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] into your question? Like, did you read that in English/other? Was it a translation?

Comment: hopfully they fined the person for not returning the book.

Comment: @Himarm - Death is too good for them

Comment: Can you remember at all what these runes looked like?

Comment: thanks for the info, ill have a look. I'll add some edits as people ask questions

Comment: Do you remember the culture at all? Was it set in modern times, medieval, vikings, etc? Or some other sort of time-period/setting?

Comment: Could it be [The Alchemyst](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17402605-the-alchemyst)?

Comment: I was thinking perhaps the [Septimus Heap series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septimus_Heap)?

Answer (score 10):

This is a long shot, but this might refer to a library edition of the *Earthsea* trilogy by Ursula K. Leguin.  The main character through the three books was Ged, also called Sparrowhawk; he was himself a wizard, and the first book (*A Wizard of Earthsea*) followed his beginning on the island of Gont, as a precocious child, followed by his education at the wizards' college on the island of Roke.

The second book, *The Tombs of Atuan* in fact involved retrieving an item from a labyrinth (one half of the Ring of Erreth-Akbe, an item of great power in maintaining peace in Earthsea); he was opposed by a cult of women who guarded the labyrinth.

The third book was *The Farthest Shore* in which Ged, now archmage, journeys with a young prince whose true name was Lebannen (I don't recall his use-name), speaks to dragons, and journeys in to the land of the dead to once again save all of Earthsea from disaster.

Comment: nope, its not those books. but thanks for your suggestion though :)

Comment: Well, with magic, traveling by boat, and a labyrinth, it was worth checking.

Comment: its always worth checking, because you never know

Comment: That series was my first thought as well, +1

Answer (score 7):

Not all the elements you quoted are in the one I'm going to suggest, but let's try.

*The Wind on fire* trilogy, by William Nicholson.

The first book, *The Wind Singer*, tells the story of the twin Hath, Kestrel and Bowman, and Mumpo, a friend, to retrieve to voice of the Wind Singer to destroy the Morah (the evil) that lies on their city, Aramanth. There may be a labyrinth (I'm not sure, I read it a long time ago), but there were boats on land.

[image: The Wind Singer]

The saga was published from 2000 to 2002, so it kinda fits the dates.

Answer (score 4):

[The Septimus Heap books](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septimus_Heap) by Angie Sage are a possible match for the details provided. Though I haven't read them, so beware of speculation based on descriptions. They were published between 2005 and 2013.

> Different colour covers, marked with a rune, first book is blue.

While not runes, the covers do each have a single motif dominating potentially causing the confusion, the first book is dark blue and the whole set is below including a dusky yellow and a solid red.

[image: Covers]

Book 4 seems to cover the labyrinth search to find someone

> The quest of the fourth book, Queste (published in April 2008), is a journey to the House of Foryx... [Septimus] pieces together a map to the House of Foryx. When they reach the house, Septimus meets Hotep-Ra, the first ExtraOrdinary Wizard.

The series features a 'flying Dragon boat' to travel around the place.

Nothing specific for magical sites in the summaries, but it is a fairly common trope.

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to search for a series just like this that I read as a kid. Couldn't for the life of me remember. Messaged my old friend from primary school. It was the [*Old Kingdom* Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Kingdom_(book_series)) by Garth Nix. Great Series.

See this collage of the different book covers in the series showing the runes on the book covers matching your memory:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why this matches? Plot wise? Covers?